# We need a flag for migrate comment to answer

Tags: feature-request

I see some great answers in comments. complete well written on topic or maybe an edit or two, but answers, not comments.

Comment: I think this has been proposed on Meta.SO, but I can't find it. This is better posted there, since such a flag would be used across all sites.

Comment: Kit, feature requests can be made either place (SE monitors the per-site metas, though infrequently), but you'll get more and faster attention on MSO.

Comment: This has been raised on Meta.SO, and didn't gain much traction: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54762/flag-a-comment-as-should-be-an-answer

Comment: It's a bummer, really. The feature could prove very useful on many, many sites of the network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comments are (by design) limited in length; while it's possible to provide something of an answer in the space of a comment, it's better for answers to be more fleshed-out.  Sometimes you can actually do that in 500 characters, but in general, comments converted straight into answers probably won't be very useful answers.  If you see a comment that has the beginnings of a good answer -- or a complete one for that matter -- please feel free to comment back to that person and ask that it be worked into an answer.  We've seen that happen to good effect here.

I would be reluctant to create answers on behalf of other users; it feels kind of like putting words into his mouth.  Even if they're his words, he chose to comment when he could have answered, so he may have had a reason. If the reason was "oops, didn't think about it" then the approach above will produce the desired result, but if he had a different reason, we shouldn't override his decision.  Answers are more visible and more permanent than comments and they affect reputation; creating them should be the author's choice.